# Regex.Matches return type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, list

My problem is on this line:

```
Dim groups As List(Of String) = (From m In Regex.Matches(str, "\d{2}") m.Value).ToList()
```

Not working in vb.net this code  ... **`m.value`**

This is my code in vb.net...

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim dezena As String = TextBox1.Text

    Dim strs As New List(Of String)() From { _
     "0203040610121415161727343738414246474852", _
     "0406080910111415273536394148495154565860", _
     "0709101416171819202229313943475354555758", _
     "0102030506080913151921232631343646505153", _
     "0106081213161925262930333840434757585960", _
     "0709121516192728303235444547505154555657", _
     "0308111316171821273235373840414344454952", _
     "0103040607091518222728303134363945465556", _
     "0406121316202225353637383942434445495660", _
     "0105070912141820212630373840434446525558", _
     "0105060714182325273031323436374548515556", _
     "0108141620222325263536394142444849505159" _
    }


    Dim linha As Integer = 1


    For Each str As String In strs
         'here is error line
         Dim groups As List(Of String) = (From m In Regex.Matches(str, "\d{2}") m.Value).ToList()

        If groups.Contains(dezena) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(linha)
        End If

        linha += 1
    Next

End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: What's the exact error?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `Select` keyword:

```
Dim groups As List(Of String) = _
  (From m In Regex.Matches(str, "\d{2}") Select DirectCast(m, Match).Value) _
  .ToList()
```

Comment: Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Object)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'.

Comment: @Ozzy: Right, you need to tell the compiler what the type of `m` is. I added the cast above.

Answer (score 0):

the correct code is :

```
Dim groups As List(Of Object) = (From m In Regex.Matches(str, "\d{2}") Select m.Value).ToList()
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing your answer*.